# Error : No module named 'telegram' - How can I resolve this error?

Tags: python, python-telegram-bot

I get this error mainly when using Pyinstaller.

Comment: how did you install the module `telegram`?

Comment: Re *"Machine translation is used"*: For the error message (only)?